# Who has the right to sport a Shikha?

Tags: varna, shikha

Can Shudras, non-initiated Brahmanas, Kshatriyas, Vaishyas etc. sport a Shikha?

Comment: I think there is a difference of opinion regarding this. Some authorities say shudras/uninitiated persons must also sport a Sikha where as others say it is not necessary

Comment: Nitya Karma Prayoga books give mantras to chant while tying the Sikha. One mantra is for the Dvijas and for the rest another one given.